# Bootstrap Modal Popup Form Code Not working

Tags: css, asp.net, html

**ASP.NET**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="#loginModal" />

<div class="container">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="loginModal"
        data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        &times;
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputUserName">Username</label>
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Login Username"
                                    type="text" id="inputUserName" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Login Password"
                                    type="password" id="inputPassword" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                            data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Don't know why the above code is not working form me.

Comment: Any Error in console ?

Comment: No errors.  Web page loads and when I click the button I am not getting the popup form :(

Comment: Not sure how buttons from ASP.NET works, but to open a Bootstrap modal, you need `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#myModal"` attributes to the element that will open the modal

Comment: Include bootstrap js file after jquery's file.

Comment: try adding `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"` in ur asp button

Comment: Since you are using `<asp:Button/>` with `runat = "server"` it may postback. Use the html button `<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Button</button>`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the button a bit, by adding `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#loginModal"`, and changing the value of `OnClientClick` to `"return false"` to prevent re-loading of page due to postback

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" OnClientClick="return false" />
```

More on [**Bootstrap Modals**](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/) *(although the documentation uses a normal button)*

Comment: I applied it and when I click the button nothing happens :(

Comment: 1. Try making the modal a direct child of `<body>` 2. Don't make the button a child of `<form>` 3. Can you use a normal button instead?

Comment: Yes, tried both but no luck am I missing any script reference?

Comment: Put `jquery.min.js` above all `.js` files first

Comment: Done but still no success :(

Comment: Kinda...weird...Check the Developer's Console *(F12)*, and see if any error occurred.